# Check if 1 timestamp is later then current timestamp

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a script that counts delivery time... so... timestamp of the orderdate - current timestamp shows a time...

this all works fine. But sometimes there are orderd where the client can set a time or date in the future..

so for those orders i dont want to show the counter but what to do something like this (all timestamps are 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

```
$time1 = date($orderItem->elapsed_time); //now
    $time2 = date($orderItem->orderdate);

    if ($orderItem->later_order_date LATER THEN $time1) {
        $elapsed = "not started"
    }
    else {
        $elapsed =  $elapsedTime->getElapsedTimeOld($time1,$time2);
    }
```

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime()` objects are comparible which makes this easy:

```
$time1 = new DateTime(); // No need to pass it anything to represent now
$time2 = new DateTimedate($orderItem->orderdate); 

if ($time2 > $time1) {
    $elapsed = "not started"
}
else {
    $elapsed =  $elapsedTime->getElapsedTimeOld($time1,$time2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function which will convert your formatted date from `YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` to a unix timestamp, which is just a number you can compare with regular comparison operators:

```
if (strtotime($orderItem->later_order_date) > strtotime($time1)) {
    $elapsed = 'not started';
}
```